# How to draw a square with the mouse

Tags: java, jframe, draw

What I'm trying to do is basically the thing you can do in the desktop when you click and drag te mouse making a square. The problem is I don't know how to make it draw "backwards" or how to clean the previous parameters when you start a new square. here is the entire code:

```
public void paint (Graphics j){
 super.paint(j);
   j.drawRect(x,y,z,w);

}

private void formMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    x=evt.getX();
    y=evt.getY();

    repaint();       
} 

 private void formMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
    z=evt.getX();
    w=evt.getY();

     repaint();
}
```

Comment: In fact, I'm not sure this is the entire code :) what is your problem exactly? Do the previous rectangles remain? What class does this one extend? Do you have a `MouseAdapter` somewhere?

Comment: ar you drawing on your desktop wallpaper? **: )**

Comment: no, is not the entire code, but is the core, the problem is i dont know how to draw in the opositte direction.

Comment: Please post an SSCCE(http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Does this work right now for forward squares? The signature for drawRect is `drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)` not `drawRect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)`

Comment: yes i know, that two last variables are to rgister the positions where the mouse is dragged and that x and y cordenates are the widht and height (z and w).

Comment: @user3362366 in your example though, you're not calculating width nor height. Consider your mouse went down at 10, 10. And you dragged to 20, 20. That would register a square that starts at 10, 10 with a width of 20. Your bottom right corner will be 30, 30 instead of 20, 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for drawRect is: `drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)`. You need to calculate the top left corner of the square, and the width and height.

The top-left corner is `(min(x, z), min(y, w))`.
The width is `abs(x-z)` and the height is `abs(y-w)`

Putting this together we get

Try

```
j.drawRect(Math.min(x, z), Math.min(y, w), Math.abs(x - z), Math.abs(y - w));
```

Why does this work? Well you're given 2 points. It's a well known fact that 2 points can determine a square(opposite corners). The first problem is that you have to translate the points you're given, into an input that java likes. In this case, you first need the upper left hand corner. You don't know which point you have is that corner, or actually it could be that neither of them are.

So what **do** we know about the upper left corner? We know that it's x value is the smallest x value that exists in the square. We also know that at least one of the 2 points given rest on that same edge. Using this information we can determine that the x coordinate of the top left corner is the smallest x value of our 2 points. Or `min(x, z)`. We use the same procedure to find the y coordinate.

Now width and height are easy. The width is the right edge - the left edge. We don't know which point is the right side, and which is the left side, but it doesn't matter. If we take the absolute value of the difference will always give you the positive difference between the points. In this case `abs(x-z)`. The process is the same for the height.

As for resetting the square try adding a `formMouseReleased` method and setting x, y, z, w to 0.

Comment: thanks man you are awesome!!! that worked, i would like if is not problem a more detailed explanation of that instruction.

Comment: @user3362366 I wrote a few sentences explaining why it works. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might create a method that resets the parameters
something like: void modifyMouse() in your Mouse class
//your parameters=0

I might try to give you a better help if you clarify your question, for now try that.

Comment: Yes that helped,but im still unabled to draw oppositte direction, i think i need a instruction that changes the place of the variables. x and y for w and z (that are the weidth and height)